# Jquery и контент в editable iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Здравствуйте,

подскажите пожалуйста как работать с выделенным фрагментом в iframe - например мне нужно выделить текст в редактируемом ифрейме и заменить одни конкретные теги на други, к примеру b на strong. Как получить доступ к самому контенту этого iframe - это ясно, а вот имено конкретно к выделению - я не понял.

спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В IE можно использовать document.selection:

```
var range = document.selection.createRange();
// манипулируем содержимым выделения
var newHTML = "<mytag>" + range.text + "</mytag>";
range.pasteHTML(newHTML);
```

Здесь: [AUI Library : jQuery : jquery.selection.js (source view)](http://docs.atlassian.com/aui/3.0/jquery.selection.js.html) есть код плагина для jQuery, но я не проверял, как он работает.

Comment: Не, это то все ясно, мне нужно именно через jquery, чтобы можно было воспользваться всякими там replaceWith , find и т.д., но не во всем iframe , а исключительно внутри выделенного юзером контента